# Scale up cTakes GUI for HiDPI Monitor

Tags: java, apache, ctakes

Does anyone know how to scale up Apache's cTAKES GUI to be larger on HiDPI monitors?

Comment: I dont think this question is relevant to any of the tags you mentioned n the question

Comment: Maybe, but cTakes is written in Java and is an Apache product. Therefore the question would pertain to editing settings (if any) in Java to make it scale properly on a HiDPI monitor.

Comment: @Kenpachi did you get ctakes gui working?